# В чем суть метода .call?

Tags: javascript

```
Предположим, что уже существуют и объект, и функция.
function f(){}
var o = {};
Выполнение кода:
f.call(o, 1, 2);
Равносильно следующему коду:
o.m = f;
o.m(1, 2);
delete o.m;
```

По пути изучения js наткнулся на данный метод, но сути так понять и не могу. Может, кто даст хороший гайд или обьяснит, в чем прикол?

Comment: Ваш пример можно растолковать вот как - o.f( 1 ,2 );  
То есть, первый параметр метода call? это контекст, контекст это this, this это ЗДЕСЬ!  
Получается, что передавая в в контекст объект о, Вы как бы на текущий момент связываете метод с объектом. И получается o.f( 1 ,2 ); И на момент этого вызова, this в методе f будет ссылаться на область объект о.

Comment: @vas, маленькая поправка: this - это "этот" а "здесь" это here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прикол здесь в ручной установке контекста функции. Под контекстом понимается объект `this` внутри функции.

```
function f(x) {
    alert(this);
}

var o1 = '123';
var o2 = '456';

f.call(o1, 0);    // выведет 123
f.call(o2, 0);    // выведет 456
```

Если контекст не устанавливать, то им станет объект `window`. Примером применения смены контекста явлвятся jQuery. В этой библиотеке в каждом колбэке контекст устанавливается в объект, с которым работает колбэк:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    console.log(this); // здесь this - это элемент #btn
}
```

Comment: а 0 в вызове какую роль играет?

ну и F(o1); тоже самое выведет....